# when doing a ActiveRecord::Base count how do i order by count desc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

an example would be...

```
Pets.find(:all, :select => 'count(*) count, pet_type', :group => 'pet_type', :order => 'count')
```

returns the correct results but not the actual counts in the orderedhash object returned.

```
Pets.count(:all, :group => 'pet_type')
```

returns the count but are not sorting in a descending fashion... how would i do this?

I think i'd prefer to use .find .. but i'll take .count if i can sort it.

Comment: I think the problem with using find to get the counts... is that aggregate/calculated columns don't come over to the object as a colum/field.   ( i likely said that wrong )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pets.find(:all, :select => '*, count(*) AS count, pet_type', :group => 'pet_type', :order => 'count')
```

Comment: This returns an array of Pet objects and no value for the counts seen.

Comment: You can access it with array.first.count and array.first.pet_type

Answer (score 0):

```
Pets.find(:all, :select => 'count(*) count, pet_type', :group => 'pet_type', :order => 'count DESC')
```

Comment: It returns an ordered hash of pet_types w/o counts.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with MySQL but might not transfer well if you switch DBs:

```
Pets.count(:all, :group => 'pet_type', :order => 'count(*) DESC')
```

Comment: No go for me under sqlite3. They are still out of order.  I could do operations on the object returned after the fact.. but i was hoping for something in the find/count method.

Comment: What version of rails? I just noticed that rails 3 returns an OrderedHash from the count method. I also just tried this with rails 3 and a sqlite DB and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@pets=Pets.include(:meals_per_days).sort do |a,b| 
  a.meals_per_days.size <=> b.meals_per_days.size
end
```

Note : This will returns an array of records, not an ActiveRecord:Relation.

Note2 : Use size, not count, as count will execute sql calls to the db.