# How to sort results by count and return in order of most to least using active record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `searches` table, which has all the searches that get run on our site. I want to pull up the most popular searches. Like say there are 130 records with the column of `phrase` being `"cheese"`, how do I sort the results by count and return them in order of most to least using active record?

Comment: This SO question might lend a hand, similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207889/when-doing-a-activerecordbase-count-how-do-i-order-by-count-desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the example I [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207889/when-doing-a-activerecordbase-count-how-do-i-order-by-count-desc) in the comments above.

```
Searches.find(:all, :select => '*, count(*) AS count, phrase', :group => 'phrase', :order => 'count DESC')
```

Although I just tried this on my own sqlite db and it worked fine (rails 3)

```
Searches.count(:all, :group => 'phrase', :order => 'count(*) DESC')
```

Comment: I ended out using the new active record interface: `Search.group('phrase').count`